# Angular: How to make $scope.gridData accessible in whole class?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, class-variables

I have this piece of code:

```
orders.controller('OrdersCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, $location, $notification, $routeParams) {

        // this works
        $scope.initGrid = function () {
              $scope.gridData = new kendo.data.ObservableArray([
                { artist: "Pink Floyd", track: "The dark side of the Moon" },
                { artist: "The Beatles", track: "I've just seen a face" },
                { artist: "Queen", track: "Innuendo" }
              ]);

              $scope.gridColumns = [
                { field: "artist", title: "Artist" },
                { field: "track", title: "Track" }
              ];

        };
        // this does not working
        $scope.update = function() {
                $scope.gridData[0].set("track", "Hey you");
        };

    });
```

After click on button in template:

```
<button kendo-button ng-click="update()">
  Update from code
</button>
```

I got always the following exception:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

**Question is:**

How can I make scope grid data accessible from another method?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS edit scope with same name from another method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24326384/angularjs-edit-scope-with-same-name-from-another-method)

Comment: Do you call `initGrid` before `update`? It looks like gridData isn't initialized, yet. Did something else clear it out? The two `$scope` variables are the same one. Maybe you can create a fiddle.