# AngularJS edit scope with same name from another method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I would like to update some value in scope with same name in another method of same class.

Problem is that update method is not working if i'm trying to update scope named **gridData**.

Should i use **scope apply or something Simillar in Angular?**

Here is my code:

```
orders.controller('OrdersCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, $location, $notification, $routeParams, ApiService) {

    $scope.gridData = {};



    $scope.initGrid = function () {
          $scope.gridData = new kendo.data.ObservableArray([
            { artist: "Pink Floyd", track: "The dark side of the Moon" },
            { artist: "The Beatles", track: "I've just seen a face" },
            { artist: "Queen", track: "Innuendo" }
          ]);
          $scope.test = function() {
              console.log('dede');
          };
          $scope.data.test,$scope.gridColumns = [
            { field: "artist", title: "Artist" },
            { field: "track", title: "Track" }
          ];
    };

    $scope.update = function() {
            // empty JSON object
            console.log($scope.gridData);
            // Here i get error
        $scope.gridData[0].set("track", "Hey you");
    };
```

Thanks for any example how to do it correctly.

Comment: I don't quite get your problem. If `$scope.gridData` is an empty object, `$scope.gridData[0]` will of course be undefined, so it will throw an error.

Comment: Of course, but before update is called function initGrid where is gridDataFilled.

Comment: you're not actually calling initGrid in this code...

Comment: Also, seeing that you asked the exact same question yesterday (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24326384/angularjs-edit-scope-with-same-name-from-another-method): Please restrain for asking the same question multiple times.

Comment: @M21B8. Init is called from template.

Comment: Have you tried: A first to check that griData is not undefined and griData length is the right one, second, instead of set, try gridData[0].field="test1", gridData[0].title="test2", is just to start pin pointing where is the problem.